# how to make select html return values from database using sql and php

Tags: php, html, sql

I have created a table called `subject` My goal is to use php to return the name of each subject and the associated price.

The table contains the following columns `subjectId`, `subjectname`, `subjectprice`. The name and price from the table should get displayed in the following html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="subjectid">
   <?php include('database/db.php');

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `subject`';
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($showdata= mysqli_fetch_array($query)){?>
       <option value="<?php  echo $showdata['subjectId']; ?>"><?php  echo $showdata['subjectname']; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
    </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: It is always helpful if you add the error you're receiving

Answer (score 0):

**You can try your while loop like this -**

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <select name="subjectid">
    <?php
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `subject`';
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while($showdata=mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
               $selected = ( $showdata['subjectId']=="id_for_compare" ? ' selected' : '' );
              echo '
              <option 
              value="'.$showdata['subjectId'].'"'.$selected.'>'.$showdata['subjectname'].'</option>';
            }
    ?>
    </select></div>
```